# How to center numbers in a table column with the siunitx package?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I've been trying and searching for quite some time, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong:

I want to create several table columns with decimal numbers (some in the format "1,25" and some like "3,156" or "12,247").

I tried:
(The *vertical lines* are only for seeing clearly where the columns begin and end.)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[round-mode=places, round-integer-to-decimal, round-precision=2, 
table-number-alignment=center,
round-integer-to-decimal
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize

\begin{tabular}{|S| S[round-precision=4]| c }
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$A_{max}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$A_{max}$} & test \\
1,2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345\\
1,23 & 1,23 & 1,23\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
1,23456 & 1,243456 & 1,23456\\
%11,23456 & 11,23456\\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'd like the whole "number block" to be centered in the width of the column, however, in the result the decimal point seems to be the centered in the S-columns:
[image: Example Screenshot]

From my understanding of the `siunitx`-manual, the option `table-number-alignment=center` should do exactly that, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `table-number-alignment = center`, you also need to set up the space to reserve using the `table-format` option. In your case, `table-format = 1.4` would be appropriate.

Comment: thanks, Joseph! My error was: I thought that `table-format = 1.2` would round the numbers to 2 digits after the decimal point, but it seems to only to define the alignment of the number in the column and the number of decimal digits has to be defined with e. g. `round-precision=2`

Comment: @Martin: Someone recently asked more-or-less about this 'Why does `table-format = ...` not round?', to which the answer is that I'd prefer people to have to choose _explicitly_ to turn on rounding.

Comment: that's perfectly ok, I just did not expect it (maybe because I'm being used to using  Microsoft Excel which does both at the same time)